# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in angular with Spring-boot / Http call angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

> I'm trying to get data to ***angular application*** from ***spring boot server***
>   via ***angular http call***. Also I have added **security** dependency for spring boot application.

When I'm trying with browser this will come.

[image]

Once I enter them with the password in console of Intellij it will show the response.

[image]

> When I'm trying with angular http call it fails and show error on
>   topic.

My angular component has following code.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    http.get('http://localhost:8080/resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
}
```

My spring boot application has below code

```
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public Map<String,Object> home() {
      Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
      model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      model.put("content", "Hello World");
      return model;
}
```

Also i have read about **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** but it is unclear how to apply those to angular.

My error is:

[image]

Comment: It's not related to angular. You have to enable CORS in your server. Checkout how to do that in your server.

Comment: I thought i have to fix angular side. thank u

Comment: Basically you have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your url in the header of HTTP options response from your server.

Comment: This article may help you: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_enabling_cors

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") didn't worked for this. @NiK648.

Comment: I have solved this applying `@CrossOrigin` annotation at controller level

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What I have done in angular application was correct and had to correct
>   my spring boot application only.

The only change I made is creating configuration file called **WebSecurityConfig.**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926480/how-to-enable-cors-at-spring-security-level-in-spring-boot-solved

Comment: I did like in above example only but in my case oauth security also there. Your example not working for me why? Please  go through this link to visit my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579277/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-th

Comment: Check this. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: My Case is with spring mvc 4.3 version not spring boot.

Comment: So it is no wonder that my answer is not working for you. What you have to do is find a way that do the above thing which could apply for your situation.

Comment: could you please tell me the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

In scala + spring boot you can add cors mapping

```
class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

  @Value("${cors.origin}")
  private val corsOrigin: String = "all"

  override def addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry): Unit = {
    if(corsOrigin=="all"){
      registry.addMapping("/**")
    }else{
      registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(corsOrigin.split(","):_*)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the server also accepts http method 'OPTIONS'. because if the domain is different browser by default sends OPTIONS request and the response should be a success 200. if its a spring back-end

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I'm new to this can you explain little about where to put this code.

Comment: I think that your answer will match with my one. Please tell me how to apply this to my code. @VithuBati

Comment: in the filter itself, you can put. I updated my code and accept it as a correct answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Every method in controller needs to be allowed the Cross-Origin individually. Simply add @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") at top of the method, hope this will do the trick.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
}
```

Comment: No,I tried. it doesn't work. shouldn't i set **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** here?

Comment: You don't need to; just add the Method type for the method, like it is GET or POST.

Comment: you mean @GetMapping(path = "/resource")

Comment: No, i tried. it says **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**