# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, The response had HTTP status code 401

Tags: jquery, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cors

I have been implementing Spring(4.3) Restful application which is having spring security and oauth(2) based configuration. After Implementing these configurations I have tested my rest api calls through postman and all is good, but my client is jquery or ajax only. When I'm trying to call oauth token it shows "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access" Error, I have configured cors enable configurations also. But I don't know which part I have missed, please help me. After so many suggestions on google I also tried with filter approach as well spring security configuration approach. But still getting same error.

## My Server Code

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", 
            "PATCH","OPTIONS"));
 }
}
```

=======================================

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    //.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/contact").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

            .httpBasic();
    // .realmName("CRM_REALM");

}
```

============================================

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
            "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH","OPTIONS")));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

**Client Code**

```
 var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "http://10.10.1.13:8080/OauthCrud/oauth/token",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "authorization": "Basic b2F1dGhDcnVkOm9hdXRoU3VwZXJTZWNyZXQ=",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "22b603e4-bf59-b722-d758-f51a1fe1a1d4"
          },
          "data": {
            "username": "rama",
            "password": "rama",
            "grant_type": "password"
          }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Your OPTIONS handler needs to not require authentication — because browsers never send the Authorization header in the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. Right now your server is responding to the preflight OPTIONS request with a 401 error — because it’s not seeing the Authorization header it expects. Instead your server needs to always respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 success code — even unauthenticated requests.

Comment: could you please explain more or what should i change in my code?

Comment: Where should i set 200 success code for OPTIONS

Comment: Me also getting same error. Please show me the way how to allow OPTIONS requests

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?